# Navigation Drawer is blank, buttons work

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, android-toolbar

So i was trying Navigation Drawer and Toolbar (Lollipop) for my first time and i've came a cross a problem that i'm struggling to find a solution.

I've managed to put it to work ***with*** Action Bar, but after i configured the new ToolBar to work with my app (and consequently taking action bar off), my navigation drawer is showing nothing but a white panel. Also, it seems that its buttons are working, because when i click a spot in the blank area, the navdrawer immediately closes.

layout_toolbar.xml
[image: My Toolbar]

activity_homepage.xml

[image: Main Screen XML]

(Resume of) ActivityHomePage.java

[image]

The problem itself

[image]

Edit: Variables definition

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Change in `setAdapter(...`     **this**   to  **getActivity().getBaseContext()**

Comment: I omitted that part from my post, but you can guess that it is already defined...

Comment: What i was trying to say is that when i created my post i already had my string array defined. I just omitted it from the image to save space.